# some words sounds like "one lump group"

Tags: pronunciation

it sounds like a narrator [is speaking](https://youtu.be/CK_PE9ILJjQ?t=461)

> if you're
>   comparing five things and you find four
>   of them share a pattern. don't talk about
>   each of them individually, put all four
>   into **one lump group**. These four countries
>   from the West are all increasing their
>   military spending, the one country in the
>   South is decreasing.

The transcript gives "one lump group", which does not make sense.

I can't hear the "one lump group" part clearly, could some help to listen it?

Comment: First impression: 'one lumped group' = 'one group which has been lumped (= grouped) together'. It's a  strange thing to say, but a Google search for "one lumped group" (with quotation marks) shows a very small number of results.

Comment: That speaker is very fluent but I detect an accent which tells me he is not a native speaker. Sounds German.

Comment: [Concise Oxford English Dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4XycAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA849&lpg=PA849&dq=define+lump+%22put+in+an+indiscriminate+mass+or+group%22&source=bl&ots=S48S4A6bsQ&sig=ACfU3U1TMYzUp2nKS3Tv4LjqIJFQZy2UoA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizkr7J1JfpAhUTQEEAHYd7CfwQ6AEwB3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20lump%20%22put%20in%20an%20indiscriminate%20mass%20or%20group%22&f=false) **lump** (verb) *1 (often **lump things together**) put in an indiscriminate mass or group*. It's relatively unusual to use the Past Participle adjectivally (as ***one lumped group***), but "colloquially acceptable"

Comment: 'Lumped' has an established usage in mathematical treatments of problems in physics, electrical engineering, etc, e.g. "The lumped-element model of electronic circuits makes the simplifying assumption that the attributes of the circuit, resistance, capacitance, inductance, and gain, are concentrated into idealized electrical components; resistors, capacitors, and inductors, etc. joined by a network of perfectly conducting wires."

Comment: In fact, 'lumping' in general usage has a sense of (sometimes excessive) generalisation or simplification.

Answer (score 1):

There's a common phrase "one lump sum." that's probably what it's supposed to say.
It's used mainly in money.

A common example is with the lottery. If you win $100 million, they give you two ways of receiving it. 
Either you could receive a monthly payment for the next 20 years, which adds up to $100mil. ($416,666.66 a month for 240 months)

Or, you could receive a major portion of it in "one lump sum."
In that case, they'll take all of the money you should be getting over the course of 240 months (20 years), minus the interest that would have accrued.
 They "lump it" into one "sum" of money.

A lump is a something compacted together.
When you are mixing a batter, and some of the flour hasn't dissolved properly and clumps up together. That's a lump.

So when used in money, it means the money is being collected together into one compact amount, or "sum" of money.

From money, this term is then borrowed to other topics.
So in the context of a political discussion they would use it to refer to nations.
Instead of discussing various nations individually, you could discuss them in "one lump sum."

While I can't currently access the video to check if that's the term being used, I imagine it's so since that's a common English idiom which fits the context.

Answer (score 0):

It's common to say "lump things together", meaning, to consider a number of similar things as a group. We usually use this wording when they're not exactly the same, but we are treating them the same to simplify things. Like, "Let's lump all our customers who order small applicances together and see ..." This phrasing is often used to criticize over-generalization. Like, "Just because one Ruritanian is a criminal doesn't mean all Ruritanians are criminals! You can't lump people together like that!" But it can also be used just to mean you are simplifying, possibly oversimplifying, but not necessarily.

So here, for example, he says to lump "four western countries" into one group. That is, even though these countries may be different in many ways, they are similar in that they are all cutting military spending, so he will put them into one "lump group".